# How can I import Excel float data into SQL Server with ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

Can someone explain theory this solution? And I have simple code

```
var PersonID = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value;//คอลัมน์ 1
var PersonName = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value;//int type in sql
var PersonAge = worksheet.Cells[row,  3].Value;//char type
var PersonCity = worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value;//char type 
var PersonBugged = worksheet.Cells [row,5].Value;// Float type

lsTestdbl.Add(new testdbl
                  {
                      id = PersonID  == null ? "" : PersonID.ToString(),
                      name = PersonName == null ? "" : PersonName.ToString(),
                      age = PersonAge == null ? "" : PersonAge.ToString(),
                      city = PersonCity == null ? "" : PersonName.ToString(),
                      bugget = PersonBugged == null ?"" ; PersonBugged.ToString()
                  });
                }
```

I already can import type char into SQL Server successfully, but the float and int I don't know how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert(parse) strings to required types.

```
int num = string.IsNullOrEmpty(PersonID) ? 0 : int.Parse(PersonID);
double bugged = Convert.ToDouble(PersonBugged);
```

Comment: which line should i add

Comment: There are several ways to parse string to required type. `double.Parse(PersonBugged)` `double.TryParse(PersonBugged, out val)` `Convert.ToDouble(PersonBugged)`

Comment: Also you may require a `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` parameter to recognize comma `,` and dot `.` as delimeter. Example: `double.Parse(PersonBugged, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: trying but not work :<

Comment: On which step do you get error? While converting strings or while saving data to database? Do you use entity framework or pure SqlCommand Text

Comment: int num = string.IsNullOrEmpty(PersonID) ? 0 : int.Parse(PersonID);
double bugged = Convert.ToDouble(PersonBugged);

Comment: yes type char i can impot ok
but float and int i cant import from excel to sql